# Onscreen navigation buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a question about design in an android app, since android phones have "physical" back buttons, should i still have onscreen navigation inside the app or is that a bad idea?

Like this for example:

[image]

I have seen some apps that have it, but im not sure if they are neccessary.

Answer (score 2):

Bad idea, you should use the action bar for on screen navigation.

Please check:
https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 1):

Folow the design guidelines, have a read of this and you'll understand the best practices regarding back and up navigation:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly discouraged to use the Back button in Android App since every Android phone/tablet has physical Back button. It is also suggested that "Don't use labeled back buttons on action bars". This can be verified from following:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html